# how can I set up a form with dynamic fields according to user input?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I set up a simple form with Chronoform V4. One of the field need to be kinda dynamic.

for example, 
  do you know your id, if yes, then input id.
if not, then there are other filelds need to be filled, such as name, birthday, sex etc.

but if you know the id, those fields should be grey out or something etc.

How can I do this in joomla? Many thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet?  Hop on the forums over at www.chronoengine.com -  not only are the developers super friendly, I have seen them custom code stuff for their users more times than not.

They know the stuff best and will definitely be able to help you.

That said, there are ways to add custom code snippets to chronoforms - I recommended using javascript to accomplish your goal.  I have done something similar and chronoforms + javascript = wonderful result.

If you've created your form with their wizard, go into your forms and click Wizard Edit.
From there on the right hand side you should see an 'Events' tab - click that.

In the 'On Load' event, you'll want to add 'Load JS' from the menu on the left.  Then you can open that, and add your javascript to control your choices.  The javascript will load when the form does and you can control the user selections exactly how you're requesting.